# How to set 2 apps on MobileFirst server with Server Configuration Tools

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I feel confused about set 2 apps on MobileFirst Server with Server Configuration Tools.

what i must do? add new configuration or add new runtime on the same configuration with my old app ??

Comment: 2 apps of the same runtime or another app that belongs to a different runtime?

Comment: i want to know setting 2 apps with the same runtime and different runtime, do you have a tutorial how to set 2 apps on MobileFirst Server ?

Comment: @RobbyWH have you understood my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi asper you Question you just want to have a single `.war` File nothing but the Server configuration file.

This is what we configure in our Server configuration Tool (War file configuration).

The next step is configuring your application and adapter in your War file via Worklight/mobilefirst console.

Where we select our `.wlapp` and `.adpater` files. (This,for you is two different applications two `.wlapp` files)

So you don't need to do any changes in the server configuration tool as far as the two `wlapp` uses the same `war` file.

---

This assertion needs further clarification/investigation:

> If you want to have two different `war` files then the question which
>   you have asked should have two `.war` files so that you should create
>   two worklight/mobilefirst server instance to deploy them and that
>   can't be done in a single server instance.

---

> TO MAKE YOU UNDERSTAND CLEARLY ILL SAY YOU VIA ECLIPSE
>
> 1. If you have two application under single mobilefirst project then the above you asked is simple just deploy you another `.wlapp` file in
>      the same `.war`  file created worklight console.
> 2. Else if you have two mobilefirst project then the above you asked is not possible you have to have two separate server instances to
>      deploy your two `.war` files.

[image]

> In above the TESTAPP and TESTAPP2 are two different application as you have asked they are in the same server instance. This doesn't have to do anything with the server configuration tool except you are build this server instance with that tool  and `war` file. The two applications should be deployed with the help of the `choose File` in the above picture and choosing the `.wlapp` files.

Comment: I don't agree that two WAR files cannot be deployed to the same server. This is possible - that's what JEE servers do: run many WAR files. It's just not so obvious using the tools.

Answer (score 0):

Kawinesh's answer above addresses the scenario of a single MobileFirst Project containing multiple applications. The Project contributes the WAR file and we then deploy the wlapp files via the resulting console, or using command line tools.

What do you do if you have two Projects? Each with one or more apps? You have two WAR files and need to deploy them both. These WAR files can coexist on the same JEE sever, and in Studio-based development this "just happens", we simply Run On Server and the WARs are deployed. But what about a server-only deployment?

The crucial thing to note is that each WAR will need its own set of database tables. I find using a customised ant task (samples are provided with the server installation) to be the easiest way to do this.

Simply copy the example and reference two different databases, or different database schemas. This example is for DB2, there are samples for other DBs.

```
<target name="install">
<configureapplicationserver contextroot="${worklight.contextroot}">
  <project warfile="${worklight.project.war.file}"/>
  <applicationserver>
    <websphereapplicationserver installdir="${appserver.was.installdir}"
                                profile="${appserver.was.profile}">
      <server name="${appserver.was85liberty.serverInstance}"/>
    </websphereapplicationserver>
  </applicationserver>
  <database kind="Worklight">
    <db2 database="${database.db2.worklight.dbname}"
         server="${database.db2.host}"
         user="${database.db2.worklight.username}"
         port= "${database.db2.port}"
         schema = "${database.db2.worklight.schema}"
         password="${database.db2.worklight.password}">
    </db2>
```